# Error establishing a database connection in wordpress

Tags: database

I know this is self explanatory but why can't I connect to my database? I have a live website that I wanted to update by first doing development in my local computer. I exported the db to my local pc then imported it to phpmyadmin. When I try to access the site thru localhost/sitename, the error ***Error establishing a database connection*** keeps popping up.

I have tried every tutorial and forums out there but still the error persists. I have checked the credentials from wp-config.php and it was the same(same db name, username, password). Is there other contents should I change property?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure MySQL user you have created is configured to connect using "localhost" in the hostname, NOT "%". Go to PHPMyAdmin -> Users -> Make sure your user is set to connect using "localhost" rather than "%".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue some days ago with a multisite, loading a live dump to local development. After some debugging I noticed, that the error message wasn't right.  
The database was connected, but the path in the database to the sites was wrong.  
You can check table `<your-prefix>_site` and `<your-prefix>_blogs` if columns `domain` and `path` are correct.  
That solved my problem, as the error message told something else.